# Altium Gerber Import Wrong Dimensions

Tags: altium, gerber

I am trying to import Gerber files into Altium Designer. However, I always receive something broken instead of the original structure.

Even if I export the structure directly from Altium to Gerbers, and import it back, it is broken.

[image]

[image]

Observing the dimensions of the imported track, it seems that it is one hundred times smaller. I have tried to make some changes in **Preferences -> CAMT Editor -> Import/Export**. But nothing worked so far.

Comment: This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).